# delay function in kafka streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

was trying something with the kafka streams code and wanted to add delay or something like threads.sleep() for 1ms after splitting data....I m confused how to do that..can someone help me out in doing that?

```
KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();
KStream<String, String> textlines = builder.stream("INTOPIC");
KStream<String, String> mstream = textlines
    .mapValues(value -> value.replace("[",""));
    .mapValues(value -> value.replace("]",""));
    .mapValues(value -> value.replaceAll("\\},\\{" ,"\\}\\},\\{\\{"))
    .flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(value.split("\\},\\{")));
mstream.to("OUTTOPIC");
KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder, config);
streams.start();
```

So after .flatmapvalues statement I need to add a thread.sleep() for 1ms so what can be my statement there..?

Comment: can you elaborate why you need sleep? (Is this really an XY problem?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you want to achieve, but it seems you want to slow down processing? Than you can just put a sleep into your use code. For this, your lambda expression must call "sleep" before it returns the actual result. As an alternative, you can also add an additional `.foreach()` or `peek()` call and sleep there.

Comment: exactly what use-case is there to slow down processing? If this is a dependency/race-condition issue, I'd highly recommend doing the processing conditionally downstream in something like NiFi instead.

Comment: thanks for the reply... so the thing is I will be getting stream of arrays every second [{"json data"},{"json data"},{"json data"}] like this...I wanted to split this. so I wrote the above code for splitting the records inside array.....now I need these records to come one after the other rather as a bunch so I am planning of slowing down the process, or what might be the best solution?   These records should go to stream reactor from confluent kafka where the stream reactor will accept the input one after the other..it cannot accept the data as a bunch like my code produce

Comment: As mentioned. You can do a `foreach()` after your `flatMap` and just sleep within `foreach()`